# How to combine two powershell scripts for AD Reporting with Foreign Security Principals

Tags: security, powershell, active-directory, auditing

I'm a DBA tasked with querying info from AD for a security audit. I need to create a Report that can put all AD objects into a CSV and resolve the Foreign Security Principals from another domain. I do have a trust between the domains. I have following script working in powershell coming from: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/59d99252-2b1c-490e-818c-d1a645332293/powershell-ad-group-membership?forum=ITCG&prof=required

```
$D = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
$Domain = [ADSI]"LDAP://$D"
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$Searcher.PageSize = 200
$Searcher.SearchScope = "subtree"
$Searcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://" + $Domain.distinguishedName

# Specify attributes to retrieve.
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName") > $Null
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName") > $Null

# Hash table.
$MemberList = @{}

# Retrieve all users, groups, and computers.
$Searcher.Filter = "(|(objectCategory=user)(objectCategory=group)(objectCategory=computer))"
$Results = $Searcher.FindAll()
ForEach ($Result In $Results)
{
$DN = $Result.Properties.Item("distinguishedName")
$Name = $Result.Properties.Item("sAMAccountName")
$MemberList.Add($($DN), $($Name))
}

# Filter on all groups.
$Searcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=group)"
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member") > $Null

$Results = $Searcher.FindAll()
ForEach ($Result In $Results)
{
$Name = $Result.Properties.Item("sAMAccountName")
$Line = """DN,$Name"""
$Members = $Result.Properties.Item("member")
ForEach ($Member In $Members)
{
    If ($MemberList.ContainsKey($Member))
    {
        # Substitute the sAMAccountName from hash table.
        $Line = $Line + ",""" + $MemberList[$Member] + """"
    }
    Else
    {
        # Use the Distinguished Name.
        $Line = $Line + ",""" + $Member + """"
    }
}
$Line
}
```

Then I found an script coming from http://activelydirect.blogspot.com/2011/01/dealing-with-foreignsecurityprincipal.html#comment-form , My hope is I could add the following to the first script and get them to resolve. But any input is welcome.

```
$securityPrincipalObject = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($object.cn)
    ($domain, $sAMAccountName) =    ($securityPrincipalObject.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).value).Split("\")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is will the second script work for translating a Foreign Security Principle from a trusted domain into a username, then yes, I have used similar code to do so with good results.  Just be sure that what you pass to the System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier constructor is only the SID of the FSP (e.g. "S-1-5-21-...") and not the distinguishedName or "CN=S-1-5-21-...".

UPDATE:

```
if ($dN.StartsWith("CN=S-"))
  {
    $SIDText = ($dN.Split(","))[0].SubString(3)
    $SID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $SIDText
    Write-Output $SID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
  }
else
  {
    Write-Output $dN
  }
```

Comment: thanks for explaining. AD security structure and querying is all foreign to me. Would you be willing to share your similar code or be will help me merge the two scripts together. My knowledge this kind of syntax is limited.

Comment: All I do is a simplistic test on the distinguishedName to see if it looks like a foreign security principal and do a translate if it is.  You could insert a similar test wherever you would otherwise output the distinguishedName itself.  I've added a code sample to my answer.

Comment: i will check it out tomorrow morning and mark answer then.